# A part of a plot is shaded

Tags: plotting

How can we obtain a plot that is shaded in a part. For example this plot:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can use [`Prolog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html):

```
Plot[Cos[x],{x,-6,6},
     Prolog->{Opacity[0.2],Rectangle[{3,-1},{6,1}]}]
```

This gives

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- To fill the actual bounds of range of plot as OP, we use `Scaled` or `ImageScaled`.
- For the range of OP, we set `{{.7, 0}, {1., 1.}}` as the range, see the illustration as below.

```
Graphics[{LightBlue, Rectangle[], LightRed, 
  Rectangle @@ {{.7, 0}, {1., 1.}}, Black, 
  Text[Style[{.7, 0}, 14], {.7, 0}, Background -> Yellow], 
  Text[Style[{1, 1}, 14], {1., 1.}, Background -> Yellow]}]
```

[image]

- When we need the shadow does not cover the `AxesLabel`.

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x", Red, 15], Style["y", Red, 15]}, 
 Epilog -> {GrayLevel[.3], Opacity[.5], 
   Rectangle @@ Scaled /@ {{0.7, 0}, {1., 1.}}}]
```

[image]

- If we need to cover the `AxesLabel`, we should use `ImageScaled` and `PlotRangeClipping -> False` instead of `Scaled`.

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x", Red, 15], Style["y", Red, 15]}, 
 Epilog -> {GrayLevel[.3], Opacity[.5], 
   Rectangle @@ ImageScaled /@ {{0.7, 0}, {1., 1.}}}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]